# Running Two Website On EC2 Or Alternative Hosting

Tags: web-hosting, amazon-ec2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I've been developing and planning to launch my website using amazon EC2. I'm planning to launch Two website, one after the other but realise that i cant share the EC2 Instance. As everyone know Magento is a CPU monster and i'm planning to run on High-CPU On-Demand Instances, Medium $0.183 per Hour, that cost like $120 per month.

I'm based in singapore and only aim to have customer coming from Singapore. So far, amazon speed has been satisfactory perhaps because they have one datacenter here in Singapore.

Here are some requirements
Two Magento Website (One require SSL in future)
Running For BITNAMI LAMP stack as i'm not very familiar with setting up server.
I'm planning to have stuff like varnish , externsion by magento, not sure if it would conflict.

I was thinking if i could make good use of the CPU power by running it on 2 site instead of just one :\

Any other alternative ? and whts your suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Security Vs Cost**

You should factor in the security risks involved in running to shops on the same server, this can lead to security risks if one was to be hacked. So I would prefer to go with 2 servers for the additional costs.

**Factor in Your Running Costs into Your Margins**

As with any good business running costs such as proformence on servers and security costs should be factored into your Margins on the products or services you sell. It should be seen as a return of investiment as your BUYING something but also receiving that money back. I know its good to save costs whenever possible but 2 servers does add additional security if just one was to be hacked or go down for whatever reason.

**What if...**

What if one server goes down? you lose both sites. I know there's nothing saying it will happen but What if? would you prefer one to keep running and if both would go down would this lose more money if just the one went down? Things to think about.

**Clouds are not always the best option**

If you really want to cut costs then moving to a dedicated server will run both sites without a problem while keeping your costs down but again this means less security and more hardware failure a possibility.

**Personally**

I advise all my clients when setting up online shops you should never try to keep down server costs since these are your primary methods of receiving income.

If attempt to cut costs on primary revenue generators then your fundamentally gimping your company. With any business plan before setting up a business things like this should be factored in, increase the margins on your products or services and go with whatever is more secure, best performance and ultimately is best for your customers. The most important factor of any online shop is price and reputation - such cutting can come and bite you.

Comment: I Agree to a certain extend, looking at spot instance. I will definitely be wiling to spend and not cut cost, but as a start-up, i will try , will look in to spot instance strategy and worst case scenario, Will have them both on a seperated server.